# How to subscribe on Resource Exhaustion Diagnosis Events?

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling

I want to know when Windows 7 detect that my program use too much memory. So I want to handle this. How I can subscribe to this event (before application will be closed).

Some info from Windows Logs:

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory.
>   Event ID: 2004
>   Keywords: Events related to exhaustion of system commit limit (virtual memory).

[Detecting Low Virtual Memory Conditions in Windows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikelag/archive/2010/09/04/detecting-low-virtual-memory-conditions-in-windows-2008.aspx)

Comment: That's not the way it works, it is not necessarily your program that triggers the condition.  You just happen to be on top of the list of piggies that take their unfair share.  You cannot intercept it, the condition is detected in kernel mode.  Buy more RAM, allow the paging file to get bigger, stop being a piggy.

Comment: Do you think 32Gb RAM for notebook is enough? Or I must to disassemble and add 4 more memory slots for 64Gb RAM? ;) BTW I solved problem. This event very easy to subscribe and handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("System", ".", "Resource-Exhaustion-Detector");
eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
eventLog.EntryWritten += eventLog_EntryWritten;

static void eventLog_EntryWritten(object sender, System.Diagnostics.EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Entry.Message.Contains(Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)))
   {
      Logger.Error("Our application consumed too much memory `{0}`. So we stopping work right now to prevent reboot OS.", new object[] {e.Entry.Message},MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
      GC.Collect();
      //do smth                
   }
}
```